# How did Java programmers survive before annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

Before the introduction of annotations in Java, how was the same functionality achieved?

Such a huge portion of what I do every day in Java involves annotations that I can't imagine what it would be like to program without them.

What would be an alternative way of achieving the same functionality without annotations?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, as annotations can be used to do dozens of things.  Exactly what are you doing with annotations that you want to ask about?

Comment: Dunno.  I grew up before annotations, so I very rarely use them.  It's one of those things where occasionally it's useful, but I often wonder why they bothered to add them.  :-)  You just get used to what's available at the time.

Comment: @Brian: that sounds pretty dysfunctional. I grew up before annotations as well, but I am very aware that they turned some aspects of Java programming (Most notably EJBs) from a horrible, inhumane brain-torture into something simple and downright pleasant.

Comment: @Dieter Gantz: Honestly I don't know, even though I've been coding in Java since 1999.  The thing is, you need to realize that **today** most Java programmers are still not using @NotNull and dealing with countless pointless NullPointerException that would never happen in the first place should they use the @NotNull annotation.  I guess 98% of the Java programs out there aren't using @NotNull, which is mindboggling.

Comment: You could emulate annotations in javadoc if you had to. Early versions of TestNG did that for java 4 compatibility. You had to point the runtime towards the source directory.

Comment: Extensive use of base classes. Cf the difference between JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 annotations.

Comment: Conventional naming. Test methods in JUnit starting with test, for example.

Comment: this is a legitimate question, people understand what it refers to and there are informative answers. DON'T BE A NAZI. Just because you don't get it, doesn't mean it's meaningless.

Comment: Some of us *still* don't know how Java programmers survive.  I was going to ask how Java programmers survived before closures, but some quick googling shows that's still the case.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [XDoclet](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/index.html) - basically a code generator that takes information from the Java source code and custom javadoc tags.
- Marker interfaces like `Serializable`
- Naming conventions (test methods in JUnit)
- And yes, lots of XML config files. Be very glad you haven't had to live with those.

Answer (score 6):

Alex, I would take XML for $400.

Comment: @Peter: I think he is referring to Jeopardy

Comment: the famous gameshow Jeopardy? I for one think it a creative answer and it deserves an upvote just for humor. :)

Comment: @Shervin: Correct.  You now have control of the board. ;)

Answer (score 6):

They where two techniques:

- One was to use XML configuration files, related to your Java classes (an example is JPA XML configuration files).
- In some cases, where your just needed a marker on a class, marker interfaces where used. Is consists in having an interface with no methods, and you can check at runtime if a given object implements this interface. One pretty common sample is `Serializable`.

Answer (score 3):

By writing a lot of xml configuration files.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean; I don't use annotations, but here I am still alive as ever.

Comment: You're actually undead, you just don't realize it.

Comment: I don't use annotations, I don't use XML (except for XHTML). I also avoid Ant and Maven.

Answer (score 3):

Other ways (beside XML config files--which probably also includes use of Spring) would be lots of properties files.

Answer (score 2):

- Properties file.
- XML configurations
- Text-based custom files.
- Interface class file with many constant fields....

Answer (score 0):

They are very nice features but they are creating more confusion for me as  I used to define them in comments e.g. @author, @return, and @deprecated etc. I skip most of the comments and therefore, It creates more confusion rather than a convenience for me.

Comment: Annotations and Javadoc tags are two totally different things even though they look similar. A good editor should use syntax highlighting to make them look clearly different.

Comment: I know they are different and coloring them might work for some people, but I also do programming in Perl and my eyes are trained for symbols like @, $, and %. It is because of this @ that ignore some important piece of code.